# Excel is not updated with interop in C#

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, excel-interop

I have the following code that based on the found value in an excel i have to update the other cell values in that row. But it is not updating the values back to the excel sheet. MasterTable is of DataTable which has the same column values as the excel i need to update these values to the excel. please help me find the issue.

```
 for (int row = 0; row < masterTable.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            // Get the CIS ID
            string CISid = Convert.ToString(masterTable.Rows[row][RemoveSpecialCharachtersAndSpace("SOW / CIS No")]);

            Excel.Range range = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Find(CISid, System.Type.Missing, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);
            //FindRangeCISByID(CISid);
            if (range != null && range.Rows.Count > 0 && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(range.Rows.Cells[1, 1].Value2))))
            {
                for (int cell1 = 1; cell1 < 5; cell1++)
                {
                    //Master Excel Copy
                    string masterColumnCopy = Convert.ToString(range.Rows.Cells[1, cell1].Value2);
                    // Local Data table copy  of column value
                    string datatableColumnValue = GetColumnValueFromDataTable(masterTable, cell1);
                    xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Find(CISid).Cells[1, cell1].Value = datatableColumnValue ;
                }
            }
        }  



xlWorkbook.Save();
                xlWorkbook.Close();
                xlApp.Quit();`
```

Comment: r u trying to export the values from datatable to excel

Comment: not entirely there are some values that i need from this datatable and based on these values i need to apply formatting also to some of the cells so i need to use Interop .

Comment: Are you saving your changes? I see you update the values but not save the file.

Comment: please see the updated code , yes, i am updating the file at the end of the loop after all the updation done i have tried to update inside the loop also but it is not updating back to excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As odd it sounds , but it is working with saveAs function for work book not with the save.

I have changed the save code to the following

```
xlWorkbook.SaveAs(@"D:\ExcelData_new.xlsx", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
       false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
       Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

and it is working